# Check if element is not in an array to open a window

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

what I am doing here is some kind of a chat interface with your online and offline contacts which you can drag around the window. I m stuck trying to create a function to check if you already opened a chat window to avoid duplicated windows. This is the link of what i got so far.  s2.enigmind.com/jgonzalez/nodeChat I hope you guys can see it.

This is the function in which I append the window elements this function get some parameters that i obtain from a JSON, the parameters are user id name and status.

```
function displayChatWindow(user, status, avatar, id){
    var template = _.template($("#windowTemplate").html(), {userName: user, userStatus: status, userAvatar: avatar, userId: id});
    stackingWidth = stackingWidth - boxWidth;
    /*console.log(stackingWidth);*/
    $("body").prepend(template);
    $(".messages-container").slimScroll({
        height: '200',
        size: '10px',
        position: 'right',
        color: '#535a61',
        alwaysVisible: false,
        distance: '0',
        railVisible: true,
        railColor: '#222',
        railOpacity: 0.3,
        wheelStep: 10,
        disableFadeOut: false,
        start: "bottom"     
    });
    $("#" + id).css({
        top: absoluteY,
        left: stackingWidth
    });
    $("#" + id).find(".minimize").on("click", displayOthersChat);
    $(".chat input, .chat textarea").on("focus", cleanInputs);
    $(".chat input, .chat textarea").on("blur", setInputs);
    addWindow(id, stackingWidth);
}
```

what I have in my global scope is an array called `var openedWindows = [];` and in this array I am appending the user id and position with the addWindow function.

```
function addWindow(id, offset){
    openedWindows.push({
        id: id,
        offset: offset
    })
}
```

So far, every time i open a new window this one is added to the array, I've been using a for loop to see if the user and id is already in the array, but i don't actually know how to structure my code, because there is no way to check at the first time if the user is in the array because the array is empty, I  will appreciate if you guys know how i could achieve this, I know my code is not the best, all this is for my learning purposes so i accept all kind of tips! Thank you very much.

Comment: You can just do `$("#" + id).length` to see if that element exists, no need for an array really ?

Comment: I didnt think about it before o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are already using underscore.js , so why not use its `_.each()` function to loop over all entries in `openedWindows`:

```
function addWindow(id, offset) {
    var found = false;

    _.each(openedWindows, function(el, idx) {
        // 'el' is an item in openedWindows, and 'idx' is its position in the array
        if (el.id === id) {
            found = true;
        }
    });

    if (found === false) {
        openedWindows.push({
            id: id,
            offset: offset
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: also, adding variables to the global scope is a really bad idea.  Either fix the scope of `openedWindows`, or change your code so you don't need an array at all.

Comment: yeah, well im new with javascript, i don't have so much experience on doing this kind of things, so im researching and reading on how i could do this in javascript oriented to objects but i still dont get it very well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! this worked really good,  i used it inside another function, the one who checks the JSON and now is working really good, i also was reading about the _.each function in underscore but i actually dont get very well how it works, i mean like the function with element and index :/

Comment: `_.each()` is passed an array and a function.  What it does is run that function once per element in your array.  The first argument to the function is an item from your array, and the second argument is the index of that item in your array.  So if `openedWindows` had 10 items, the function would be called 10 times, and passed a different item from `openedWindows` each time.